# Can't access unallocated old internal HDD on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 at new HDD.

And now want to move my work files from old hard drive to new.

I caught some trouble with this, I can't access this disk now.

But all was correct during installation (connection was established and worked perfect).

Here is my `lsblk`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-art-System-Product-Name ~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1   3,8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1   3,8G  0 part /media/nazar_art/8BAA-7FA6     // usb driver
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk                                // new HDD
├─sdb1   8:17   0   6,5G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 459,2G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0 149,1G  0 disk                                // old HDD
```

It can see my usb driver from which was installed Mint. But now it doesn't see old HDD.
Any suggestion?

**Update:**

I can only create new partition.

It shows unallocated disk.

[image]

I not sure that this new partition doesn't damage information... ?

Any suggestion?

A little bit more information:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/8BAA-7FA6
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0 464.8G  0 part /
├─sdc2   8:34   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdc5   8:37   0  1022M  0 part [SWAP]

nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00060485

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ sudo file -s /dev/sda
/dev/sda: x86 boot sector, code offset 0xb8
```

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu with this old disk plugged in, and select the option to "Erase everything and install Ubuntu"?

Comment: @searchfgold6789 Of course, that not. I chosen install Ubuntu but for another disk. This was plugged but I didn't touch during installation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

- 160GB(149GB) HDD contains important data.

It appears that this disk does not contain a valid MS-DOS partition.

How that happened is for now beyond me, but first and foremost
**DO NOT** proceed with any operation that will write **anything** to disk.

And before this question progress to "How to recover files from disk without valid partition?" I have to ask: Do you have a backup of your important files?

Comment: If you need to recover the files, you can do so with [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) if you haven't written to the disk yet.